# Uploaded file isn't created on the server

Tags: symfony, file-upload, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to upload files with Symfony2 but while I don't get any error in return or in the log, the uploaded file isn't created on the server. I'm testing the upload with a dummy small text file.

Here is the code for the document entity, [from the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) :

```
<?php

namespace Crm\EntiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Doc
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    private $temp;

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/docs';
    }

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (isset($this->path)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->path;
            $this->path = null;
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->path = $filename.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }
        $this->file = null;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        $file = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        if ($file) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my (testing) controller:

```
public function uploadAction(Request $request)
{
    $document = new Doc();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
        ->add('name')
        ->add('file', 'file')
        ->add('submit','submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($document);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response();
    }

    return $this->render('CrmEntiteBundle:Form:upload.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The route for the uploadAction:

```
crmentite_upload:
    path:   /upload
    defaults: { _controller: CrmEntiteBundle:Entite:upload }
```

And here is the (simple) Twig:

```
<form {{ form_enctype(form) }} action="{{ path('crmentite_upload') }}" method="POST">
     {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>
```

Here is the HTML generated:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/web/app_dev.php/upload" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="required" title="Ce champ est requis">*</span>
                    <label class="control-label required" for="form_name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="form_name" name="form[name]" required="required" maxlength="255" class="form-control" />

    </div><div class="form-group">
                    <span class="required" title="Ce champ est requis">*</span>
                    <label class="control-label required" for="form_file">File</label>
        <div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Parcourir&hellip; <input type="file" multiple></span></span><input type="text" class="form-control" readonly></div></div><!--div class="input-group col-md-10"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>&nbsp;Parcourir&hellip;<input type="file" id="form_file" name="form[file]" required="required"></span><input type="text" class="form-control" readonly></span></div-->

    </div><div><button type="submit" id="form_submit" name="form[submit]" class="btn btn">Submit</button></div>            <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" class="form-control" value="p_JPyYzTR2Es37Eocp_X2WkG0GtrJUJH9_ZvyuEj29U" />
</form>
```

For information, I've previously created the `uploads/docs` folder, with correct rights, and a record is added to the doc table.

A `var_dump($this->getFile());exit();` in the `upload` function return `NULL`, same for the `preUpload` function.
A dump of `$request->files` is empty, as a `$_FILES` one.

Comment: you can vardump some $this->getFile() in your upload function to check if it is executed at least and that the file is correctly set in.

Comment: It returns `NULL`...

Comment: @NawfalSerrar  It only contains `{{form(form)}}`

Comment: @NawfalSerrar a var_dump in the preUpload function also return `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your twig :

```
<form {{ form_enctype(form) }} action="{{ path('youruploadactionroutename') }}" method="POST">
     {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>
```

i think it may be the enctype which is not set. 
You may wanna try to put in your form builder

```
->add('file', 'file')
```

## edit :

input field didn't have name or id of the form, it was an error in the html, more specifically in `field.html.twig`:

```
{% block file_widget -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Parcourir&hellip; <input type="file" multiple>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock file_widget %}
```

Corrected:

```
{# with error #}
{% block file_widget -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Parcourir&hellip; <input type="file" multiple {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock file_widget %}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't worked. BTW, with only `form(form)`Symfony2 already generated the enctype of the form, it correctly detected the type of `file`.

Comment: does var_dump the request have the uploaded file at least? $request->files

Comment: It doesn't seem it contains it, the request file bag is empty. If I dump all requests, I only have `name`, `submit` and the token in return.

Comment: the request is this right ? use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; otherwise what does the $_FILES have?

Comment: Yes the request is right, and $_FILES is also empty.

Comment: Route added, as the generated HTML.

Comment: euh your input file doesn't have a name, i dont think it is normal, the commented html otherwise have it why is it commented?

Comment: Dooh! You're right, it's the cause of my problem, I had an error in my field.html.twig, it's working now!

Comment: Set dummy code for filed.html.twig, I'll edit your answer with my code after. Already thanks for your help!